# Заполнение таблицы HTML посредством PHP и MySql

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно заполнить таблицу если она сделана вот в таком формате ?

```html
<h2>Цены на ремонт КПП</h2>
<figure class="wp-block-table is-style-stripes">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Услуга </td>
        <td>Цена, рублей</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена сцепления МКПП</td>
        <td>от 3500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена МКПП</td>
        <td>от 3500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Снятие/установка МКПП</td>
        <td>от 4000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Капитальный ремонт МКПП</td>
        <td>от 8000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла МКПП</td>
        <td>от 800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена сальника МКПП</td>
        <td>от 5000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена ручки МКПП</td>
        <td>от 2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена тросов МКПП</td>
        <td>от 1000 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена ШРУС наружный</td>
        <td>от 1600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена ШРУС внутренний</td>
        <td>от 2500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в муфте Халдекс</td>
        <td>от 1500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в редукторе заднего моста</td>
        <td>800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в редукторе переднего моста</td>
        <td>800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в раздаточной коробке передач</td>
        <td>800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в КПП/CTV вариаторного типа</td>
        <td>от 1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена масла в АКПП</td>
        <td>1800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Замена АКПП /CTV</td>
        <td>от 9000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ремонт АКПП</td>
        <td>от 8000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```

Потому что нашел только способ заполнения td

```
 // read data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["first_name"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["last_name"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["email"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row["address"] . "</td>
                <td>
                    <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='update'>Update</a>
                    <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href='delete'>Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>";
```

Грубо говоря, нашел метод, который заполняет tr в котором много td, а нужно чтобы заполнялась 2 td в каждом tr

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Ознакомтесь в темой [почему не надо использовать картинки с кодом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/209304) и исправьте ваш вопрос, согласно прочитаному. Для этого нажмите [edit] под вопросом

Comment: удалите лишнее, оставьте только 2 td, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо большое за информацию! Исправил

Comment: @teran Суть в том, что если не будет этих tr то таблица будет выглядеть вообще по-другому. У меня получается сейчас всего 2 колонки в ней это "Название услуги" и "Цена". А если писать к примеру 2 услуги в одном tr, то они будут в длину, а такое к сожалению не подходит

Comment: не надо удалть tr, н адо убрать лишние td. если вам нужны только 2 ячейки, то оставьте 2 td.

Comment: Точно!! Спасибо большое, все сделал и отлично выглядит !)